# Not showing German Symbol embeded in html template in gmail using IE

Tags: html

GoodMorning!!

Wanted a little help. Currently I am working on German html template where I want to produce this german symbol „  .In order to implement this symbol I have embedded $#132; in my html template. For Chrome browser (only for latest version) german template in gmail  is reflecting this symbol „ but not for IE in gmail.

Could you guys help me with this. Any hint will work.

Comment: It should not be any problem if the html part of you email is encoded using utf-8. There could be various reason why it does not work for you. Without knowing how you create the mail and how the final content of your mail looks like it is not possible to tell what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks Niese for the suggestion.